# Get ID Of Item With Highest Price

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with Item ID and Item Price. I'm running Oracle. I would like to get just the ID('s) with the highest price.

This works on MySQL, but not Oracle (why not!?!?).

```
SELECT Main.itemid 
  FROM Main 
HAVING MAX(Main.itemprice)
```

Since I will use this in another nested query I need to make it work using `HAVING`. Any ideas? Thanks!

BTW, produces this error:

```
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Comment: It works in MySQL (and PostgreSQL 9.1+) because the GROUP BY is optional, and non-GROUP BY/aggregate wrapped column values are arbitrary (not great).

Comment: I tried using GROUP BY, but it doesn't give me the expected result. MySQL gives me the id with the highest price. But using GROUP BY in Oracle - gives me the highest price for each individual id, so i have many results instead of 1 or possibly 2.

Comment: @OMGPonies: I don't have a PostgreSQL 9.1 installation at hand right now. But I am pretty sure the above query wouldn't work. `HAVING` expressions must evaluate to boolean, that's not the case with `MAX(itemprice)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you the distinct list of `itemid`s where `itemprice` is maximal (throughout the table):

```
select itemid
from Main
where itemprice=(select max(itemprice) from Main)
group by itemid;
```

Comment: I guess you are the closest person to the solution I'm looking for, even though it doesn't not include HAVING. Thanks.

Comment: @skynorth - I should also add that if you **really** want a `having` clause, then you can do `select itemid from (select itemid,max(itemprice) from Main group by itemid having max(itemprice)=(select max(itemprice) from Main))a group by itemid` (which first finds the maximum `itemprice` for each `itemid` and then only takes the `itemid`s where the `itemprice` equals the global maximum `itemprice`), however I'm sure this is slower than the query above (or, at the very least, not any faster).

Answer (score 2):

Edit: With `rank()` instead of `row_number()` it should now do what has been asked for:
Gets **all** items with the highest price.

```
SELECT itemid
  FROM (
   SELECT itemid
         ,rank() OVER (ORDER BY itemprice DESC) AS rn
     FROM Main)
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Actually, if you modify your window function to `row_number() over (partition by itemid order by itemprice desc)`, then it should produce the same results.

Comment: @Jack: naaah, that won't work at all. itemid is (or should be) unique, that will result in partitions of size 1, all rows will have rn = 1. But **rank()** does what is needed here. Edited my answer.